# Change a Number inside a Variable

Tags: bash, variables, sed

I have the following problem: (Its about dates)
The user will set the following variable.

> variable1=33_2016

now I Somehow want to to automatically set a second variable which sets the "33" +1
that I get

> variable2=34_2016

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Does there come a point where adding 1 shouldn't yield the next consecutive number? You said those are dates so if 33_2016 is the 33rd day of the year 2016 then +1 is 34_2016, but if you started with 366_2016 then should +1 yield 1_2017?

Answer (score 1):

My first choice would be to break the first variable apart with `read`, then put the (updated) pieces back together.

```
IFS=_ read f1 f2 <<< "$variable1"
# Option 1
variable2=$((f1 + 1))_$f2
# Option 2
printf -v variable2 '%s_%s" "$((f1 + 1))" "$f2"
```

You can also use parameter expansion to do the parsing:

```
f1=${variable%_*}
f2=${variable#*_}
```

You can also use a regular expression, which is more readable for parsing but much longer to put the pieces back together (`BASH_REMATCH` could use a shorter synonym).

```
[[ $variable1 =~ (.*)_(.*) ]] && 
  f1=$((${BASH_REMATCH[1]}+1)) f2=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```

The first and third options also allow the possibility of working with an array:

```
# With read -a
IFS=_ read -a f <<< "$variable1"
variable2=$(IFS=_; echo "${f[*]}")

# With regular expression
[[ $variable1 =~ (.*)_(.*) ]]
variable2=$(IFS=_; echo "${BASH_REMATCH[*]:1:2}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"}{$1+=1}1' <<< "${variable1}"
```

While this needs an external process to spawn (a bit slower) it's easier to read/write. Decide for yourself what is more important for you here.

To store the return value in a variable, use command substitution:

```
variable2=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"}{$1+=1}1' <<< "${variable1}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do somewhat the same thing with *parameter expansion* with *substring substitution*, e.g.

```
$ v1=33_2016
$ v2=${v1/${v1%_*}/$((${v1%_*}+1))}
$ echo $v2
34_2016
```

It's *six* to one, a *half-dozen* to another.